# expect into remote system, get output to local shell variable

Tags: variables, expect

I am trying to get an expect script to ssh into a remote system, and get the output of a remote command.
I want to have that output available locally.
As an example, ssh into the system and get the local time output:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set timeout 60
spawn ssh user@server.domain.com
expect {
timeout {puts "timed out after $timeout seconds"; exit}
"Password:"
}
send "SuperSecretPassword\r"
expect "user$ "
send "date\r"
expect "date"
expect "\r"
set buffer1 '$expect_out(buffer)'
expect "\r"
set buffer2 '$expect_out(buffer)'
send "exit\r"
expect eof
set buffer3 '$expect_out(buffer)'
exit
export VARIABLE $buffer1
export VARIABLE $buffer2
export VARIABLE $buffer3
echo "Okay, we are done expecting..."
echo "Buffer1: $buffer1"
echo "Buffer2: $buffer2"
echo "Buffer3: $buffer3"
```

Naturally, the above isnt working, and in fact the script execution ends after the expect "exit"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
log_user 0
set timeout 60
spawn ssh user@server.domain.com
expect {
timeout {puts "timed out after $timeout seconds"; exit}
"Password:"
}
send "mypassword\r"
expect "user$ "
send "date\r"
expect "date\r\n"
expect "*\r" { send_user "$expect_out(0,string)\n" }
close
exit
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to pass data from a child process (the expect script) to the parent (shell script?) is via stdio channels: the expect script has to print the expect_out buffers, and the shell script has to capture the expect output and act on it in some way.

before the `exit`, do something like

```
puts "buffer1='$buffer1'"
puts "buffer2='$buffer2'"
puts "buffer3='$buffer3'"
```

You'll probably want to turn off all other expect output. That's `log_user 0` and ... something else I can't recall ... the Exploring Expect book has all the wonderful details.

The shell script would do

```
expect_out=$(./program.exp)
while read line; do
    [[ $line == buffer[123]=* ]] && eval "$line"
done <<< "$expect_out"
```

or perhaps simply

```
source <(./program.exp)
```

---

Of course, expect is a fully-fledged and very capable language in it's own right (Tcl), and can undoubtedly do all the local stuff you need to do without having to bother with a shell script invoking expect and passing data back.